# Embedded project using Mux and Demux for antenna

Tags: embedded, antenna, wifi, gps, gsm

In our current embedded project we are implementing a GPS ,GSM and Wifi Module. To connect these modules to external antenna board,separate SMA cables are used.As our design requires each of the functionality to be done separately and not parallel, we are planning to introduce a three channel MUX on the electronics board and a demux on the antenna board so that only one cable will be utilized.. Can anyone suggest an efficient Mux and demux for this purpose

Comment: Since these services occupy different frequency bands, it's not clear that you cannot simply use a network which combines and splits all of them, without any switching required.

Comment: From what you are saying you have multiple antennas (part 1) and multiple rf devices (part 2) but you want to connect the two parts using only one cable and utilize a mux at one end and a demux at the other. Is this correct?

Comment: In addition to @ChrisStratton: GPS requires a circular polarized antenna, whereas the other two don't.

Comment: @jippie - I wasn't proposing sharing the antenna, but only the feed-line, by using frequency-specific networks on both ends.  However, many GPS antennas are active, and that would have to be taken into account in the system design.

Comment: @Andy -That is correct

Comment: This is not going to be cheap. A 3GHz 4-channel RF mux would run you about $2000, and I couldn't even find a demux (although you might hack something together with bandpasses.)

Comment: 4 Channel RF mux can be implemented with RF switches. For example, Peregrine 4283 or similar products from Hexawave and Skyworks. However, I would not mux the GPS signal. Acquisition time can be as long as 1 minute, and sensitivity is a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

Each RF subsystem that transmits needs to be fed to a duplexer (RX and TX to one feeder) then three feedpoints can be routed to a triplexer. The GPS feed point needs to be isolated by filters of the other transmitters. Feed all of them to a broadband antenna.There are saw devices available to undertake what you want.